# Is there some "scale invariant" substitute for the softmax function?

Tags: function, machine-learning, math

It is very common tu use softmax function for converting an array of values in an array of probabilities. In general, the function amplifies the probability of the greater values of the array.

However, this function is not scale invariant. Let us consider an example:

If we take an input of [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3], the softmax of that is [0.024, 0.064, 0.175, 0.475, 0.024, 0.064, 0.175]. The output has most of its weight where the '4' was in the original input. That is, softmax highlights the largest values and suppress values which are significantly below the maximum value. However, if the input were [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3] (which sums to 1.6) the softmax would be [0.125, 0.138, 0.153, 0.169, 0.125, 0.138, 0.153]. This shows that for values between 0 and 1 softmax, in fact, de-emphasizes the maximum value (note that 0.169 is not only less than 0.475, it is also less than the initial proportion of 0.4/1.6=0.25).

I would need a function that amplifies differences between values in an array, emphasizing the greatest values and that is not so affected by the scale of the numbers in the array.

Can you suggest some function with these properties?

Comment: One approach is to introduce a "temperature" parameter which scales the softmax arguments; this is an analogy to statistical physics, in which terms like exp(-E/(k T)) appear, where T is the absolute temperature and k is the Boltzmann constant, and E is energy. Note that k T has units of energy so E/(k T) is dimensionless. As T goes to zero, the maximum term dominates the others, and as T increases without bound, the terms become more and more the same. HTH. Incidentally this is a great question, but probably more suited to math.stackexchange.com or something.

Answer (score 1):

As Robert suggested in the comment, you can use temperature. Here is a toy realization in Python using numpy:

```
import numpy as np
def softmax(preds):
    exp_preds = np.exp(preds)
    sum_preds = np.sum(exp_preds)
    return exp_preds / sum_preds

def softmax_with_temperature(preds, temperature=0.5):
    preds = np.log(preds) / temperature
    preds = np.exp(preds)
    sum_preds = np.sum(preds)
    return preds / sum_preds

def check_softmax_scalability():
    base_preds = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3]
    base_preds = np.asarray(base_preds).astype("float64")
    for i in range(1,3):
        print('logits: ', base_preds*i,
        '\nsoftmax: ', softmax(base_preds*i),
        '\nwith temperature: ', softmax_with_temperature(base_preds*i))
```

Calling `check_softmax_scalability()` would return:

```
logits:  [1. 2. 3. 4. 1. 2. 3.] 
softmax:  [0.02364054 0.06426166 0.1746813  0.474833   0.02364054 0.06426166
 0.1746813 ]
with temperature:  [0.02272727 0.09090909 0.20454545 0.36363636 0.02272727 0.09090909
 0.20454545]
logits:  [2. 4. 6. 8. 2. 4. 6.]
softmax:  [0.00188892 0.01395733 0.10313151 0.76204449 0.00188892 0.01395733
 0.10313151]
with temperature:  [0.02272727 0.09090909 0.20454545 0.36363636 0.02272727 0.09090909
 0.20454545]
```

But the scale invariance comes with a cost: as you increase temperature, the output values will come closer to each other. Increase it too much, and you will have an output that looks like a uniform distribution. In your case, you should pick a low value for temperature to emphasize the maximum value.
You can read more about how temperature works [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/32477/what-is-the-temperature-in-the-gpt-models/32478#32478).